# pandas dataframe doubled, when trying to concatenate without duplicates Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I was trying to concatenate two data frames and removing their duplicates. It worked but somehow it saved both the concatenated dataframe (dataF) and a dataframne that looks like the previous given dataframe (availableData). I tried googling the error and searching it on Stack Overflow but didn't find any solution.

Here is my Code:

```
availableData = pd.read_csv("datasets/1m_inf")
data = get_data(currentTime)
dataF = pd.concat([availableData, data]).drop_duplicates()
dataF.to_csv("datasets/1m_inf", index=False)
```

What might help:

when printing dataF, I noticed, that it showed the 720 columns, that should exist in my case, but the summary showed 1440 columns:

```
0      1666530660  19154.6  19154.6  19154.6  19154.6  19154.6    0.265673      1
1      1666530720  19152.2  19152.2  19152.2  19152.2  19152.2    0.003825      1
..            ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...         ...    ...
719    1666540920  19198.0  19198.1  19198.0  19198.1  19198.0  0.13566735      5
720    1666540980  19198.2  19198.8  19198.2  19198.8  19198.4  2.60437627      7

[1440 rows x 8 columns]
```

Can anyone tell me, how to save only the final concatenated dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe `dataF` probably has duplicated indexes. You can create a new index inside `pd.concat` with `ignore_index` parameter:

```
dataF = pd.concat([availableData, data], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Just tried it, but unfortunately wasn't the solution.